# Can't read certain tables from Firebird Database

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, firebird

I've been developing a program which has to read some tables from a Firebird database and store them into Pandas' dataframes for further processing. However, even if it works for most of the tables, some of them return the error below when I try to store them:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position
>   34: character maps to

The code I've been using to read each of the tables is simply:

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
import fdb

engine= sqlalchemy.create_engine(r'firebird+fdb://user:pwd@host:port/path_to_FDB')

df = pd.read_sql(r'SELECT * FROM tableName', engine)
```

But as I said, it won't work for certain columns. And just to be clear, when I execute the command `engine.table_names()`, I can clearly see that the failing tables are present in the database. So what am I doing wrong here? And where could my problem be?

Comment: Wild guess,make sure the table doesnt have a reserved name.

Comment: It doesn't, actually :/

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace and the full message. The error suggest that you are trying to read something to string that isn't in the expected character set (eg 0x8D is invalid as the first byte of a UTF-8 character) or something that is binary (and the byte sequence is invalid in the character set). Check the character set of the column involved and/or try specifying an explicit connection character set.